# PHP glob(*) and foreach by largest number basename

Tags: php, foreach, glob

I have this files path/**0**.php path/**3**.php path/**2**.php path/**7**.php

I want to display the files with foreach and I use this code:

```
$files = glob("system/$var/$var/$var/*/*.php");
foreach($files as $file) {
    //code here per $file.
    //for example:
    $basename = basename($file);
    echo str_replace(".php",null,$basename) . "<br>";
    include $file; //heres i need the path of the files.
}
```

But I want to sort this files by the largest number that is before the .php extension, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => path/7.php
    [1] => path/3.php
    [2] => path/2.php
    [3] => path/0.php
)
```

so?

update, rsort is not good for me, because the is a path/to/file, before the numbers, i want to use the path of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the array being returned using usort:

```
$files = glob("system/$var/$var/$var/*/*.php"
usort($files, function ($b, $a) {
    return strcmp( substr($a, strrpos($a, '/') + 1), 
                   substr($b, strrpos($b, '/') + 1) ); 
});
```

Note that this will use string comparison, so 10.php will end up between 1.php and 2.php. If that's not what you want you have to use numeric comparison. i.e. using PHP 7's "spaceship" operator:

```
$files = glob("system/$var/$var/$var/*/*.php"
usort($files, function ($b, $a) {
    return ((int)substr($a, strrpos($a, '/') + 1)) 
       <=> ((int)substr($b, strrpos($b, '/') + 1)); 
});
```

---

Edit: I swapped $a and $b in the callback signatures to reverse the sorting order

Comment: can u make the secont code to work with php 5? because my hosting, is not have the php 7, the secont example is what i want.

Comment: i install 7 and its okkey, but if someone know how to do it with 5 will be very usefull!

Comment: I can't test right now, maybe using `-` instead of `<=>` is enough if usort accepts any negative/positive value. Else the idea is `if (a < b) { return -1 } else if (a >b) { eturn 1; } else { return 0 }`

Answer (score 2):

[Look at `rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php):

```
$files = glob("system/$var/$var/$var/*/*.php");

//Put each file name into an array called $filenames
foreach($files as $i => $file) $filenames[$i] = basename($file);

//Sort $filenames
rsort($filenames);

//Check output
print_r($filenames);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7.php
    [1] => 3.php
    [2] => 2.php
    [3] => 0.php
)
```

---

To preserve the full paths, you can use the paths as the keys and the basename as the values:

```
#For testing:
#$files = array("path/3.php", "path/1.php", "path/5.php", "path/7.php", "path/0.php");

//Put each path AND basename into an array called $filenames
foreach($files as $file) $filenames[basename($file)] = $file;

//Sort $filenames by basename with arsort()
arsort($filenames);

//Check output (listing the paths)
foreach($filenames as $k => $v) echo $v.PHP_EOL;

//Just the values
$filenames_with_paths = array_values($filenames);
print_r($filenames_with_paths);
```

This will output:

```
path/7.php
path/5.php
path/3.php
path/1.php
path/0.php

Array
(
    [0] => path/7.php
    [1] => path/5.php
    [2] => path/3.php
    [3] => path/1.php
    [4] => path/0.php
)
```

Comment: rsort is not working meaby because the output is "path/7.php" and not "7.php"

Comment: @user2670708 My mistake. I've corrected the code - try now!

Comment: that is working see Array ( [0] => 7.php [1] => 3.php [2] => 2.php [3] => 1.php ) but i dont want to lose the path of the files.. i have data there that i will use per file

Comment: @user2670708 I've made an edit to add that functionality - the resulting array `$filenames` is now a key/value pair, sorted correctly, where each key is the basename and the corresponding value is the path.

Answer (score 0):

User your code like :

```
foreach(array_reverse($files) as $filename){}
```

Comment: array_reverse is not working meaby because the output is "path/7.php" and not "7.php"

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob("system/$var/$var/$var/*/*.php");
rsort($files);

foreach($files as $key){
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: rsort is not working meaby because the output is "path/7.php" and not "7.php",

Comment: rsort functionality - Sort the elements of the $files array in descending alphabetical order. So it is check alphabetic also. If different path name means display order also change.